# Running python script in google colab, nohup gives ImportError

Tags: python, bash, google-colaboratory, nohup, tee

I am running these on the google colab.

On my first cell I pip installed the necessary packages

```
!pip install python_speech_features
!pip install soundfile
```

It gives the following logs, to assert they are installed

```
Requirement already satisfied: python_speech_features in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: soundfile in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from soundfile) (1.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.0->soundfile) (2.19)
```

[Cell 4 and Cell 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2nHZ.png)

> Cell 4

shows me importing python_speech_features without issues

> Cell 5

```
!nohup python run_1_Dataprep.py "conf/conf_dataprep.py" "conf/conf1_sr8k.py" |& tee run_1_Dataprep.log &
```

shows that when I tried to run a script using

- **nohup** : (so that no hiccups will happen), and
- **|& tee** : which lets me log all outputs to a log file, as well as on the terminal
- **run_1_Dataprep.log** : The log file which i want to store all terminal outputs
- **&** : to run it in the background.

These are the error message in case you cant view the picture

```
nohup: ignoring input
===========
python run_1_Dataprep.py conf/conf_dataprep.py conf/conf1_sr8k.py
2019-10-13 16:35:09.872582
===========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_1_Dataprep.py", line 9, in <module>
    from _helper_basics_ import *
  File "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/_helper_/_helper_basics_.py", line 27, in <module>
    import wave, python_speech_features#, pyaudio
ImportError: No module named python_speech_features
```

[Cell 6 : showing that i can run the normal way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpovm.png)

> Cell 6

when i just run,

```
!python run_1_Dataprep.py "conf/conf_dataprep.py" "conf/conf1_sr8k.py"
```

it runs successfully.

While i can run it perfectly in cell 6, i want to have the logs be written to a log file, hence the purpose of cell 5. why does it not detect my pre-installed package, and are there any work around ?

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd meet same problem with you.
when I run "nohup"and "&" set commands in my python virtualenv, I got error massages like:

```
nohup: ignoring input
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainer_cnn_bit_forDebugging.py", line 13, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

But when I use "python + command", it works fine.

Looking forward to answers.

========================================================================

Founded the answer:

the nohup get into a wrong python path, you can have a test.

Create a python file test.py, contents like:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Run these two commands, then you can see result like:

> python test.py

```
['/misc/Work20/wwm1995/speech_11_08_2019', '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/home/usr18/wwm1995/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
'/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', 
'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

and

> nuhup python test.py >./output 2>&1 &

open the output file

```
['/misc/Work20/wwm1995/speech_11_08_2019', 
'/Work7/home/usr18/wwm1995/.virtualenvs/ENV/lib/python2.7', 
'/Work7/home/usr18/wwm1995/.virtualenvs/ENV/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-
linux-gnu',
 '/Work7/home/usr18/wwm1995/.virtualenvs/ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/Work7/home/usr18/wwm1995/.virtualenvs/ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/Work7/home/usr18/wwm1995/.virtualenvs/ENV/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/Work7/home/usr18/wwm1995/.virtualenvs/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Work7/home/usr18/wwm1995/.virtualenvs/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Running python commands directly uses python3, but the python path found by nohup is python2. At this time, you need to specify the python version to run the py file.
Enter

> which python3

to get the currently used python path:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

In this case, just specify the python version to run the nohup file:

```
nohup /usr/bin/python3 test.py > log.txt2>&1 &
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using `sudo` can cause this problem for some reason. Instead, use:

```
nohup python3 script_name.py > output.log &
```

Or with the complete path to Python like @austin-wang specified, example:

```
nohup /usr/bin/python3 script_name.py > output.log &
```